# How to hard code BLE pairing passkey in bluez 5.x peripheral?

Tags: key, bluez, pairing, hardcode

**I need to have a hard coded passkey pin (eg "123456") in my peripheral device so that android mobile will have to enter this code while pairing.**

*I am using ubuntu 18.04, bluez 5.48 and a TI BLE4.0 + wifi chip on board.*

Currently, I am able to establish pairing using all other methods which are provided by stack (noinputoutput, Keyboardonly,displayonly and keyboarddisplay).

**My peripheral device will not have display and keyboard at production and hence planning to use a unique key which is stored in a file.**

**I have tried modifying simple-agent code to return a fixed key..I also tried tweaking bt-agent code to pass a passkey file.. but all these methods cant be used because stack is creating a random key and not taking my static hard coded key** :(

I could see dozens of similar questions in web but none with a correct answer.. I had previously worked on few other BLE chips and achieved the same requirement(cc2650 etc with their on controller chip and stack), but with bluez stack I am not able to do it.

I heard that older stack had feature to read pin from a file, but how to achieve same in new stack?

Following points are mandatory i hope?:
 1) I have to disable hci0 sspmode 
 2) I need Bluetooth daemon service to be running
 3) I need an agent for pairing

**Please let me know if anybody out there achieved the same with bluez...**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The Bluetooth standard says the passkey should be random for each attempt. There's a good reason for that: the security property of the protocol is broken if a passkey is reused (at least for LE Secure Connections). So you should probably stick to "Just Works" method. If you need authentication, use a PAKE algorithm in your application layer.

See https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/f/nordic-q-a/35856/questions-about-lesc-mitm-and-passkey/138216#138216 for a longer description.