# BLE BlueZ return fixed pin for connection

Tags: c++, bluetooth-lowenergy, dbus, bluez

I have bluez 5.48 running on embedded device and I am able to connect Apple and Windows devices over the bluetooth. I have also been able to get Bluetooth pairing working using DisplayOnly custom agent which generates random pin/pass for pairing.

The embedded device has no Input/Output peripherals so I need to return fixed pin for all connections but for some reason I am not finding the right way to do it. So far I have created custom agent, registered it on dbus, which receives the calls `RequestPinCode` and `DisplayPasskey` (but they are set to return auto generated pins.)

here is code snippet from my set up

```
static void bluez_agent_method_call(GDBusConnection *con,
                    const gchar *sender,
                    const gchar *path,
                    const gchar *interface,
                    const gchar *method,
                    GVariant *params,
                    GDBusMethodInvocation *invocation,
                    void *userdata)
{
    int pass;
    int entered;
    char *opath;
    GVariant *p= g_dbus_method_invocation_get_parameters(invocation);

    g_print("Agent method call: %s.%s()\n", interface, method);
    if(!strcmp(method, "RequestPinCode")) {
        ;
    }
    else if(!strcmp(method, "DisplayPinCode")) {
        ;
    }
    else if(!strcmp(method, "RequestPasskey")) {
        g_print("Getting the Pin from user: ");
        fscanf(stdin, "%d", &pass);
        g_print("\n");
        g_dbus_method_invocation_return_value(invocation, g_variant_new("(u)", pass));
    }
    else if(!strcmp(method, "DisplayPasskey")) {
        g_variant_get(params, "(ouq)", &opath, &pass, &entered);
        cout << "== pass = " << pass << endl;
        pass=1234;  // Changing value here does not change the actual Pin for some reason.
        cout << "== pass = " << pass << "opath = " << opath << endl;
        g_dbus_method_invocation_return_value(invocation, NULL);
    }
    else if(!strcmp(method, "RequestConfirmation")) {
        g_variant_get(params, "(ou)", &opath, &pass);
        g_dbus_method_invocation_return_value(invocation, NULL);
    }
    else if(!strcmp(method, "RequestAuthorization")) {
        ;
    }
    else if(!strcmp(method, "AuthorizeService")) {
        ;
    }
    else if(!strcmp(method, "Cancel")) {
        ;
    }
    else
        g_print("We should not come here, unknown method\n");
}
```

I tried changing the pass variable in DisplayPasskey function to set new pin but bluetooth still connects with the auto generated pin only.

I found this stack overflow question which is exactly what I need [How to setup Bluez 5 to ask pin code during pairing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51523467/how-to-setup-bluez-5-to-ask-pin-code-during-pairing) and from the comments, there seems to be solution to return the fixed pins.

It would be great if somebody can provide me with some examples to return fix pin in `DisplayPasskey` and `RequestPinCode` functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bluetooth standard does not contain a fixed key association model. The standard does not use a PAKE (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Password-authenticated_key_agreement) but a custom ad-hoc weaker protocol. The custom protocol used during passkey pairing is only secure for one time passkeys (in particular, a passive eavesdropper learns the passkey used after a successful pairing attempt and can also be brute forced in at most 20 pairing attempts).

BlueZ follows the Bluetooth standard, which says the passkey should be randomly generated. Therefore you cannot set your own fixed passkey. If you don't have the required I/O capabilities, you shall use the "Just Works" association model instead (which unfortunately does not give you MITM protection). If you want higher security by using a fixed passkey for MITM protection, you must implement your own security layer on top of the (insecure) Application layer. This is for example what Apple's Homekit does.

Please also see my post at https://stackoverflow.com/a/59282315.

This article is also worth reading that explains why a static passkey is insecure: https://insinuator.net/2021/10/change-your-ble-passkey-like-you-change-your-underwear/.

Comment: Thank you @Emil, although it looks correct I can't understand why there is a way to create custom agent and override the RequestPinCode and DisplayPasskey APIs if we are not allowed to change its behaviour? Also, the [bt-agent](https://github.com/khvzak/bluez-tools/blob/master/src/bt-agent.c) provides way to read the pin from file (I haven't got this working either) but I am just thinking there must be some way to have fixed pin as ble in embedded evidences is common scenario. i'd appreciate any thoughts on this. thanks.

Comment: The agent API doesn't "override" anything; it implements the needed mechanisms for performing a pairing according to the spec. For example, the DisplayPasskey callback is used by Bluetooth system pairing dialogs (which use this API) to show the passkey the user shall input on the other device. I don't know why bt-agent can read from a file, but it seems to be to automate the keyboard input function if the remote device for some reason uses a static passkey. This file mechanism is useless if both devices implement the Bluetooth spec properly.

Comment: If you have the impression that fixed pin for BLE in embedded devices is a common scenario, then that's probably just due to bad programming habit. It starts with one programmer consultant that doesn't read the spec and does something bad. Then friends and colleagues copy the code/idea without reading the spec and the problem gets widespread. Just like asking yourself why commonly 20 years ago all php/asp sites doing database calls didn't escape their SQL queries and thus were vulnerable to SQL injections. Just because something seems common doesn't mean it's good or correct.

Comment: @Emil in embedded devices, there can be other means of generating the passkey, e.g. deriving the passkey from static device parameters combined with random TOTP token in the advertising data. Central device can get the passkey from the cloud after providing scanned advertising packet. This assures the passkey not only changes after every connection, but also in time periods. Anyway, in all cases we need a way to set such "custom random" pairing passkey. I am aware of the OOB, but that is not supported on all platforms.

Comment: Clever idea! If a TOTP token nonce is only used once, that could indeed be a secure option. Bluetooth stacks however follow the specification, which says the passkey should be randomly generated. But a passkey derived from a known secret and a public nonce could not really be treated as randomly generated... If this method is used anyway, that method would not comply with the I/O capabilities and otherwise allow for the correct user flow.

Comment: Thanks @Emil, sorry for the late response (very late). But you were correct. Thanks again :)